# JavaScript Date - How to better set midnight UTC+0

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, material-ui, globalization

I have a MUI Datepicker where i can select a day without time.

Example:
I select

> 01.09.1970

In console the log is `Tue Sep 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)`
It means i sitting in timezone UTC+1 and select midnight. But UTC+0 is one hour more early (that's the problem).

I already have a way to solve my problem:

```
const clonedBirthDate = new Date(birthDate.getTime());
clonedBirthDate.setUTCMinutes(- clonedBirthDate.getTimezoneOffset())
```

After it the time clonedBirthDate is

```
Tue Sep 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
```

And UTC+0 is at midnight.
I can send it to an ASP.NET Api and for every user in the world the selected day is UTC+0 at midnight. I need to do it client side because in ASP.NET i haven't a way to caculate it back to the user local time, because i don't know the timezone of the user in backend.

This code looks like a workaround. Maybe there is some better way?

Comment: If you want to treat everything as UTC, and if you can get the raw day,  month, year values out of the date picker, the Date constructor assumes UTC when supplied with a string with no time component; or the [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) function treats input values as UTC.

Answer (score 1):

We can create the Date corresponding to UTC midnight by using the [`Date/getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear),[`Date/getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), and [`Date/getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) methods to get the year, month and day, then passing them to the [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) method.

We pass the output (ms since 1970-01-01 UTC) to the Date constructor and we get utcMidnight, e.g. the start of the day 1970-09-01 in UTC.

```js
let d = new Date('Tue Sep 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
console.log('Picked Date (Local): ', d.toString())
console.log('Picked Date (UTC): ', d.toISOString())

const utcMidnight = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
console.log('UTC Midnight:', utcMidnight.toISOString())
```

You could also send the birthdate to the backend as an object, with year, month, day properties, since the hour, minute, second etc. is not relevant.

```js
let d = new Date('Tue Sep 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
console.log('Picked Date (Local): ', d.toString())
console.log('Picked Date (UTC): ', d.toISOString())

const birthDate = { year: d.getFullYear(), month: d.getMonth() + 1, day: d.getDate()};
console.log('Birthdate:', birthDate);
```